# What happens when calling CreateDirectory or CreateFile from different machines simultaneously?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to use a temp directory of a file as a lock for multiple application (from multiple computers) that need to read and write in a remote directory, but in the documentation this issue is not addressed. Does anyone know what would happen with two simultaneous calls?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Note: I know using a database would be best, but this is not possible in my case.

Comment: the way you want to use it won't work - at least not in a robust manner... the second call would simply succeed... the scenario you describe has absolutely nothing to do with "thread-safety" IMHO... although since you are using a remote directory (i.e. network/SMB share?) the specific behaviour depends on the OS version etc.

Comment: It's not really about thread safety; what you are asking is what happens if two programs try and create/read etc the same file/directoy at the same time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600471/how-to-lock-a-file-and-avoid-readings-while-its-writing for an example.

Comment: I don't know about the WIN32 API, but personally if a manual or documentation page for a function doesn't explicitly say it is thread safe, the I consider that function unsafe. Better safe than sorry and all that.

Comment: You are right about the title, I changed it.

Comment: Also, thanks for the link, but my problem is a bit different since I have multiple applications (on different machines) accessing the same file. I don't know if it's quite the same thing.

Comment: It's a race. The results are unpredictable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: this means that it is possible to have both calls on different machines returning true ? (if this is so, than this is the answer.)

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure only one will return true. Which one wins is another matter.

Comment: @Yahia: I am only using microsoft products, NTFS filesystem on all the remote shares and all the clients are using either XP or windows7

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: that would still be the answer. If you are sure about it / have some sources, please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Ha11owed It can even behave differently between XP and Windows7 - depending on several aspects one or both calls can return true... so I just would NOT go that route if you need it to be robust!

Comment: @Yahia: i have cooperating applications (no one else will try to touch in any way my files or directories) What aspects are you referring to ?

Comment: @Ha11owed I am refering to subtelities of the SMB protocol, different windows versions/patchlevels/service packs etc. which can introduce "interesting effects" into this kind of stuff in addition to a user being able to interfer. Are the machines all in the same LAN ?

Comment: @Yahia: yes they are on the same lan.

Comment: @Ha11owed Are any fiewalls active ? how many machines/applications are we talking about ?

Comment: @Yahia: no firewalls, this is a trusted internal network. There should be about 30-50 machines, but the chance of simultaneous accesses is not that great since not all the machines are started in the exact exact same moment. Also the access is very short. But the persistence aspect is important.

Comment: @Ha11owed Is there any machine/application that is "guaranteed" to be up always ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5750/discussion-between-ha11owed-and-yahia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the same directory name, from different machines, only one call will succeed. The API function will only return `TRUE` if it was the called that actually made the directory. The operating system on the machine which owns the filesystem makes this process atomic.

However, there's nothing to stop another processing getting in and deleting the directory in between the two calls to `CreateDirectory`. So whilst you can get a primitive form of locking working, it's not very robust and needs all parties to cooperate.

The same reasoning applies to `CreateFile`.

Comment: @Yahia No it does not. Thanks.